# What is the best upper bound known for the complexity of computing an optimal prefix free code in the RAM model?

Tags: ds.algorithms, sorting, prefix-free-code

In the algebraic decision tree, the result is clear: Elmasry and Belal ([Verification Of Minimum Redundancy Prefix Codes](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1614073))'s lower bound shows that the worst case complexity of computing an optimal prefix free code over all possible sequences of $\sigma$ frequencies is $\Theta(\sigma\lg\sigma)$.

In the $\Omega(\lg \sigma)$-word RAM model, combining Van Leeuwen's reduction to sorting ([On The Construction Of Huffman Trees](http://www.pubzone.org/dblp/conf/icalp/Leeuwen76)) with any $O(\sigma\lg\lg\sigma)$ sorting algorithm in the RAM model yields an upper bound of $O(\sigma(1+\lg\lg\sigma))$, which many people seem to assume to be optimal, probably by analogy with the situation in the algebraic decision tree model. But the only lower bound available is $\Omega(\sigma)$, the cost of reading the frequencies, leaving a gap between the two bounds.

**What is the best upper bound known on the asymptotic complexity of computing an optimal prefix free code in the word RAM model?** Is it $\Theta(\sigma\lg\lg\sigma)$ or $\Theta(\sigma)$? Or somewhere in between?

Comment: The private BibTeX citation keys are not helpful.  Please add human-readable citations, preferably with links to electronic copies.

Comment: Heya Jeff: I did try to make the bibtex aliases human readable, following the format Year-Venue-Title-Authors. I added two links now, but the first paper is behind a paywall and the second one is too old to be available digitally: you might have to go down to the library physically...